# How do I make a NSWindow popup when a button is pressed

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsbutton

I have a small itty bitty help button in my cocoa program. I was wondering how to make it, when pressed, to make a small nswindow panel popup, with lots of text on it. How can I do this? The button is called `help` and the window can be called `helpwin`

Comment: What kind of window would you like to pop up? Just one that has text and then buttons like "Cancel", "Ok", etc? Or are you looking to have a window with full functionality?

Comment: I edited it. I would like a panel. (it's in the ui maker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do is create the @property for my panel. Then in my button IBAction, I wrote

```
- (IBAction)help:(id)sender {
    if (![self.helpWin isVisible]) {
        [self.helpWin makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
    }
}
```

And it works!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how sophisticated your panel needs to be, you can simple pop up an NSRunAlertPanel.

```
-(IB Action)helpPanel:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger choice = NSRunAlertPanel(@"Help", @"The previous string is the titel or main message of your alert panel. This is theft can be longer. You then have three buttons to fill in, the default button and two alternate buttons. With the alternate buttons on 'nil', you get only one button.", @"ok", nil, nil);
}
```